# how can i change the text displayed according to the slider change

Tags: jquery, html

I have a slider and a text input. There's a default value for the text input, i want to make the number displayed in the text input change when i slide the slider to a different percentage. I am wondering which tag i should use that i could set a default value to it and it won't be affected by the changing result.
 I have it in jsfiddle:
    http://jsfiddle.net/8DzCE/266/

```
<table id="foodaverage" style>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">Average amount</td>
        <td></td>
        <td><div id="foodcarb" style="display: inline;">carbon footprint( <p id="unit" style="font-size: 10px; display: inline;">tons CO<sub>2</sub>)</p></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div id="simpleslider" class="slide"></div></td>
        <td><div id="simplevalue" class="answer"></div></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="528" class="result" id="foodanswer" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div id="qslider" class="slide"></div></td>
        <td><div id="asimplevalue" class="answer"></div></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="423" class="result" id="foodanswer1" /></td>
    </tr> 

</table>
```

jquery:

```
$(".slide").each(function(i,item){
    $(item).slider({
        value:50,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        slide: function(event, ui){
            var nextTD = $(this).closest("td").next();

            nextTD.html(ui.value + '&#37;');
            var percent=parseFloat(ui.value);
            var answer=nextTD.closest("td").next("input");
            var int=parseFloat(answer.val());
            answer.text(int * percent / 100);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit.

Comment: I dont see a text input anywhere in your fiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8DzCE/266/

Comment: Use the `output` element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8DzCE/272/). I believe you just had your selector wrong for `answer`. I will say though that this really isn't the best method of getting your objects, you'd be better off using IDs, OR classes and referencing them through the parent object (gets rid of all of those closest, next, etc). But for now I just changed the selector to this:

```
var answer = nextTD.closest("td").next("td").closest("td").children("input");
```

[Here is an update per the comments below](http://jsfiddle.net/8DzCE/273/).

Comment: the updated fiddle had the same problem i came through. the text value will change according to the current text value. When i slider is at the position 100%, it will never go back to the original result.

Comment: The number is wrong because your calculations are off. You are constantly multiplying by a percentage of the number that is in the textbox, which means it is getting exponentially larger or smaller. If you want to calculate based on an initial static value you will need to specify that somewhere. I updated the answer to include a second fiddle where I used hidden input fields to store the initial values. (but really you could store them anywhere)